# How do I publish a report to Tableau/BI tool with React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, neo4j, tableau-api

we have a react front-end which is connected to Express/Node.js back-end which itself relies on Neo4J database (because we need this kind of relation between data). The whole stack runs on AWS.
We would now like to interact with Tableau (we liked it, but we are open to other BI solutions if they are a better fit). The main goal is that the users of our web application will be able to create customizable reports and of course view them. They would only have access to their own data.

So my question are as follows:

1. Is it possible to interact with Tableau/other BI solution through some SDK in React/Express app in order to create reports and view them?
2. How could we make sure that a given user can only work with his data in the BI tool?

If there is a better and easier solution which will drive us to what we are trying to achieve we are opened to those ideas :)

Thanks in advance to all!

Comment: By the way I am aware that there are ways to embed the reports, which something what we would need as well. What I am rally not aware of is how those dashboards could be created through the web app.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.